# OctoPackPackageVersion variable not picked up in TeamCity on single project out of multiple in same solution

Tags: octopus-deploy

(TeamCity version 7.1.3 on Windows 2008 R2, using Octopack NuGet package 2.0.20 for Console applications.)

Having some weird issues here:  Rather than repeat the entire thread, I was hoping I could get some takers reading my linked post (short) and maybe offer some insight.

Basic issue is stated in the title of this post.

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/6435-octopackpackageversion-variable-not-usedpicked-up-in-teamcity

I have been trying to determine why in just one particular project within the same solution why it is that the OctoPackPackageVersion variable is not being passed to nuget via Octopack whereas all other projects in the solution behave as they should picking up the proper version from the TeamCity system variable defined as:

[image: System Properties]

[image]

```
...nuget\NuGet.exe" pack "bin\Release\NuGet-temp\CaptiveAire.Core.SocketServers.ServiceHost.nuspec" -OutputDirectory "bin\Release" -basePath "bin\Release\NuGet-temp" -Version "1.0.0.0" -NoPackageAnalysis
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this came down to having mixed versions of OctoPack support files: targets and newer C# targets DLL for msbuild.

See the linked support page in the original question.

Hope this possibly helps someone else.